# Compare SQL server datetime column to year month?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
 WHERE  YEAR(MDTFlgtStart)=YEAR(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(MDTFlgtStart)=MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Above code it compares with present year and month with the column year and month.
But do we have any chance we can give year=2012 month =3 
or year =2011 month=5

Comment: i expect to miss something obvious, but replace the function calls with numeric literals, eg. `... WHERE  YEAR(MDTFlgtStart)=2011 AND MONTH(MDTFlgtStart)=5`.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare variables:

```
DECLARE @YEAR AS INT
DECLARE @MONTH AS INT

SET @YEAR = 2012
SET @MONTH = 3

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE  YEAR(MDTFlgtStart)=@YEAR AND MONTH(MDTFlgtStart)=@MONTH
```

You can wrap the above in a procedure for re-usability....

Answer (score 1):

You can just use parameters for those values. As a bonus, [avoiding functions against the column will help assist a seek if an index exists on the column](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) (of course [`SELECT *` means it will likely end up as a full scan anyway, or a range scan and a bunch of lookups](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list))...

```
-- these would be input parameters for your stored procedure
DECLARE @y INT = 2011, @m INT = 5;


-- now have a date variable:
DECLARE @dt DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, @m-1, DATEADD(YEAR, @y-1900, 0));

SELECT ... FROM dbo.tablename
  WHERE MDTFlgtStart >= @dt
    AND MDTFlgtStart < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @dt);
```

Also you should stop inviting whoever named these columns to lunch, because I have to assume they're not very nice.